# How to change file permission for apache log rotation

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, log4j2

From my linux server, I deployed one web application on tomcat server. And I configured log4j to write log and rotate every hour. But when it create new log every times, it use "640" file permission by default.

> rw-r----- 1 myuser myuser       664 Jun  6 11:00 mylog.log

I am not quite sure where the configuration did for log rotation with 640 permission. I didn't define in my log4j configuration.

Please kindly advise me where I can change file permission for newly log rotation of my log4j files?

Thanks,
Tun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File permissions are determined by the `tomcat7` user's `umask` - there's no way to change it in log4j itself.

https://serverfault.com/questions/152936/how-to-set-default-umask-for-tomcat-webdav-servlet

Comment: Thanks. Now my umask is 027. Do I need to change to 022 to allow read permission to others? May be it will become -rw-r--r--?

Comment: `umask 0022` will make it read only to group and others and executable\readable\writable for the owner.

Comment: Thanks. It will be 644, correct? Is it necessary to restart server after configuration changed?

Comment: Right (I was wrong - it won't be executable..). If you changed it in `startup.sh` so yes, you should restart Tomcat.

Comment: @EidoShack Did it work ?

Comment: Yes. After i set, it is working now. Thanks for your help!